# render partial doesn't work correctly when it is nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial with a form which I use from two places (/exercise/new and /notes/new). In the second path the form is loaded in a modal within the notes view. The form has a select field which is populated with a collection, this works fine only in the first path in the second, the select is empty.

exercise_controller.rb

```
# GET /exercise/new
def new
  @exercise = Exercise.new
end
```

exercise/_form.rb

```
= simple_form_for @exercise do |f|
  = f.input :tag_ids, collection: ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :id
  = f.button :submit
```

exercise/new.html.slim

```
h1 New exercise
== render 'form'
```

note_controller.rb

```
def new
  @note = Note.new
  @exercise = Exercise.new
end
```

note/new.html.slim

```
h1 New Note
== render 'form' /! Note form
== render 'modal_create_exercise' /! Modal which calls exercise's form partial
```

note/_modal_create_exercise.html.slim

```
.modal
  .modal-header
     h4 New exercise
  .modal-body
     == render 'exercises/form'
```

In both cases: exercises/new and notes/new form is rendered but in the second option values are empty although the console displays `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.order(:name)` performed in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your last template `note/_modal_create_exercise.html.slim` contain

```
 == render 'exercises/form'
```

instead of

```
 == 'exercises/form'
```

?

Comment: Right. Filed to write. I have just changed it.